# How can i trigger a build in Azure DevOpswhen a pull request is made in Github

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps for pipelines and GitHub as my repo. I want to trigger a build in Azure DevOps when a pull request is made.

I have two branches in GitHub: master and test.

When I update test and create a pull request I want Azure DevOps to automatically build the pipeline and run it... how can i do this ?

I tried the below but nothing happens

pr:

- main

trigger:

- main

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

Comment: The official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) should cover what you need to know

Answer (score 0):

You can add [a pr trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) in your yaml pipeline:

```
pr:
- master
```

Comment: I did that but nothing happened as below  :                                                                         # Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
pr:
- main

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in the end :

```
**pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'** 
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```